# CSS Background Image Scale to Center?

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/2esv5wja/

css code snippet:

```
.imageContainer {
    height: 750px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

.imageContent{
    background: url('http://orig15.deviantart.net/0e45/f/2010/052/1/1/calvin_and_hobbes_2010_by_nami86.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 3%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
    min-width: 1200px;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Is there a way to make it so when the image stops scaling, it crops to the center? That is, as it stands, it crops from the right. Can we crop from both sides evenly? If so, how is that done?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing `</div>` in your demo.

What do you mean when the image stops scaling?

Comment: just remove `background-size`

Comment: `background-size: 100%;` means the image is always displayed at it's native resolution, there will be no scaling taking place. Can you confirm what you mean?

Comment: Oops, added them back. Anyway, when the window size gets smaller, it pushes the image to the right, effectively cropping it. Which is fine, but I want it to crop from both sides, not just one. Effectively making the center of the image the focus. Does that make sense?

Comment: Scaling is NOT the issue. The issue is the image is cropped due to the window size being to small, it crops from one side. My question is it possible to crop from both sides to the center of the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see the updated jsfiddle > [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2esv5wja/3/)

You need to scale by height in order to get the crop effect you are looking for in order to do this, please see the code:

```
.imageContent{
    background: url('http://orig15.deviantart.net/0e45/f/2010/052/1/1/calvin_and_hobbes_2010_by_nami86.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: auto 100%;
  height: 500px;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}
```

The background size property handles the scaling which is why I have changed it to be so that the width is always auto and the height is 100%, I have then added a hard height in pixels which you can change. This creates the desired effect.

Comment: This does it! Now, my next question is that the image breaks out of the bottom of the div. How can we make sure that doesn't happen?

Comment: Removing the padding from the .imageContent div should do the trick. Also if you could accept my answer as the correct one, that would be awesome! (:

Answer (score 2):

Easy answer is to set the

```
background-size: 50%;
```

Looks ok on your fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

replace `background-size: 100%;` with `background-size: cover;`

https://jsfiddle.net/2esv5wja/4/

Comment: exactly, and do read this http://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: This isn't what I was asking. Neelam got it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 background-size: 100% 100%;
```